# Azure Backup utility: Requires AD... what is the non AD alternative to this utility?

Tags: azure

Azure Backup is exactly what we are looking for.

The tool that does the data movement, is the Azure Backup utility (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49170)

Our first observation is that it requires SQL Server (that is a heavy requirement!).

But then the music stopped when it required AD.

How do we move in this direction without AD?

Comment: Where is the part that requires a domain? I'm reading [this quickstart](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/backup-azure-microsoft-azure-backup/) that implies joining a domain is optional...

Comment: @MichaelHampton Depends what tool is used, I discovered. see answer I am about to post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, there is more than one azure backup tool.

MicrosoftAzureBackupInstaller.exe : This REQUIRES an active directory server. Setup will not continue without it.

MARSAgentInstaller.exe : This is a file system only tool. It does not require AD.

Alternate: use Azure File, to mount a share to windows, and use robocopy.  https://serverfault.com/a/748465/13716